# How would Computer Science help the world in the novel coronavirus outbreak

Tags: computer-vs-human

This may seem off-topic question but I am really wondering how CS folks could help in situations like coronavirus. What novel problems arise from such disease? From CS and ML/AI perspectives, is there anything that Computer Scientists could do to better combat the coronavirus?

Comment: I think this is actually off-topic as it is way too broad. But perhaps as a first idea, CS could help in modeling and forecasting, i.e., telling us where to focus efforts.

Comment: Wouldn't the virus' DNA present NP-complete string problems? If its always evolving it would be hard to beat.

Comment: Molecular modeling! This is already being done by [Folding at Home](https://foldingathome.org/2020/03/15/coronavirus-what-were-doing-and-how-you-can-help-in-simple-terms/), and BOINC / [Rosetta at Home](https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/forum_thread.php?id=13533) projects.

Answer (score 2):

During a recent Hackathon I witnessed, a team prepared a gadget like a smart watch. The goal is to check how many times does a person cough, to track fever and such. A really cheap piece which can be worn by everyone. The data that can be attained would yield geo-coordinates of the societies and getting affected and need attention. It can help prioritize areas of immediate concern.